# Parsing html code with html error problem

Tags: magento2, phtml, php-7, html

I am getting this kind of exceptions in my exception.log . i have no idea where it comes from.

```
main.CRITICAL: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : br in Entity, line: 1

{"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 2): DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : br in Entity, line: 1 at /home/beta_angara/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php:71)"}
```

**Anyone have any idea how can i handle these kind of errors?**

Comment: In which page you are getting this error?

Comment: @ChiragPatel i don't know.it comes in my exception logs many times.i am also confused how can i debug this things. 
any suggestions?

Comment: @BalwantSingh did u fix the issue?how?